# Is 45005000 a recognisable location?

Tags: geolocation

Hello and sorry if this is not a relevant question to this SE. Please if it is not, mitigate it to where you see fit. I have recently purchased an item online and I have been provided by the seller with a tracking number applicable to this site: http://track-chinapost.com/startairmail.php . So when I check where my item is, I get Location: 45005000
Any ideas what this could mean?

Comment: No, this is encoded location

Comment: Zhengzhou International Airport

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange and thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate on how you got to this answer?